# JS set var value based on key/value pair where key is equal to the var name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I am trying to set a variable from a key value pair where the key is the name of the variable.

Let's say I have :

```
var someValue = 10;

function setValue(key, value) {
  key = value; //key is the actual name of the var i.e. "sameValue"
}
```

So the idea is to change the value of "someValue". Is this even possible in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better approach is to make use of a JSON object. To achieve that , you can always have a `key:value` JSON object where the `key` corresponds to your variable. See the example below. The variable `someValue` is actually a `key` of the JSON object `obj` then you can easily reference that to simulate as if you are calling a dynamic variable and changing its value.

```js
var obj = {
   someValue : 10
};

function setValue(key, value) {
  obj[key] = value; //key is the actual name of the var i.e. "sameValue"
}

setValue('someValue',30);
console.log(obj['someValue']);
```

Comment: Thanks @AKA that's what I thought as well. Accepting as correct.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help you

Comment: JavaScript objects and "JSON objects" are two different things. Don't use the term JSON if you mean JavaScript objects.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help you